# How can I dynamically update SVG viewBox values from Polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, svg.js, jquery-svg

I have created SVG maps of a comic book page panels.

```
<svg id="svg1413"  class="svg-pg" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 178 254" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="transition: .6s ease-out;">
    <image id="image1966" width="178" height="254" clip-path="url('#SvgjsClipPath1413')" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/yiZFUK4.jpg" />
    <g id="SvgjsG1413" clip-path="url('#SvgjsClipPath1413')" class="click-panels">
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,13 88,13 88,49 12,49"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 81,44 166,44 166,74 81,74"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,13 166,13 166,75 12,75"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 101,80 166,80 166,118 101,118"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,80 166,80 166,147 12,147"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,152 91,152 91,200 12,200"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 73,171 155,171 155,209 73,209"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,198 79,198 79,235 12,235"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,152 166,152 166,235 12,235"></polygon>
    </g>
    <defs id="SvgjsDefs1413">
        <clipPath id="SvgjsClipPath1413">
            <rect id="SvgjsRect1413" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0">
            </rect>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>     
</svg>
<svg>
    ...svg content
</svg>
<svg>
    ...svg content
</svg>
```

What I want to achieve is:

- Loop through all the <svg> tags
- while on an <svg>, loop through the <polygon> tags contained within the <svg>
- Each <polygon> contains 4 pairs of coordinates (eg. `points=" x1,y1 x2,y2 x3,y3 x4,y4"`)
- I want the parent <svg> `viewBox` values and the <rect> X and Y values to be updated with values from the current <polygon> points in the loop.

I have figured out how to calculate the values, but I don't know how to achieve this in Javascript.

My pseudo-code for calculating <svg> `viewBox` values

```
if <svg viewBox=" a b c d ">
a = x1, b = y1, c = x2 - x1, d = y3 - y2
```

Updating <rect> Values

```
if <rect x="e" y="f">
e = x1, f = y1
```

UPDATE: How do I control the transitions with click/swipe events rather than making it automatic?

```
<div id="controls" class="ctl-btn" style="width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0; margin: 0 -8px; background-color: rgba(6,6,6,0.40);">
    <div style="max-width: 800px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
        <button class="pg-ctl-bk" style="margin: 8px; padding: 8px 10px;">  Back </button>
        <button class="pg-ctl-nxt" style="margin: 8px; padding: 8px 10px;"> Next  </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get it, if you want to update your <svg>'s viewBox depending on **all the polygons in a loop**, why don't you just do it for the last polygon? viewBox can have only one value at a time, so it would do the same. Can you clarify a bit what you really are after?

Comment: I want to loop through all the polygons (like a carousel), on each polygon, I want the parent viewBox to be updated with the values calculated from the current polygon in the loop (carousel)

Comment: here is an example of what I want to achieve https://read.marvel.com/#book/41323

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure why you used <polygon> elements here, when all you needed was a javascript Array/JSON, or ultimately <rect> elements which at least have `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` attribute as requested by `viewBox` attribute, but well... let's deal with <polygon>s then...

To convert your <polygon>'s `point` attribute value to a `viewBox` attribute, the simplest is to call `polygonElement.getBBox()` which will return an SVGRect with the needed values.

To have the `viewBox` property animated, the easiest is probably to use SMIL animations, and a polyfill for MS browsers.

You simply need to define an [<animate>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate) element targeting the `viewBox` attribute, and to update its `to` attribute to the target value, after you updated its `from` attribute to the current value.

```
// animate : <animate attributeName="viewBox" ...>
// rect : {SVGRect} result of polygonElement.getBBox();
function animateViewBox(animate, rect) {
  animate.setAttribute('from', animate.getAttribute('to'));
  animate.setAttribute('to', `${rect.x} ${rect.y} ${rect.width} ${rect.height}`);
  animate.beginElement(); // (re)start the animation
}
```

Once we have this, we only need to set up a function that will iterate over all the <polygon> elements in the svg.

```js
function animateViewBox(animate, rect) {
  animate.setAttribute('from', animate.getAttribute('to'));
  animate.setAttribute('to', `${rect.x} ${rect.y} ${rect.width} ${rect.height}`);
  animate.beginElement(); // (re)start the animation
}

// container
const svg = document.getElementById('svg1413');
// all the <polygons> coordinates (would be better as JSON...)
const polygons = svg.querySelectorAll('polygon');
// <animate> element
const animator = svg.querySelector('.viewBoxAnimator');

// our iterator, we could call it on click
let i = 0;

function iterate() {
  if (i < polygons.length) {
    animateViewBox(animator, polygons[i++].getBBox());
    return true;
  }
}

// but we'll automate it
(async() => {
  while (iterate()) {
    await wait(1500);
  }
})();


function wait(time) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time));
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  transition: all .6s;
}

html {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<!-- SMIL for IE -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Kaiido/FakeSmile@1e50d675df616a8e784e0e6e931b3f0d595367d4/smil.user.js"></script>

<svg id="svg1413" class="svg-pg" width="154" height="83" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 178 254" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <animate class="viewBoxAnimator" attributeType="XML" attributeName="viewBox" from="0 0 178 254" to="0 0 178 254" dur="0.6s" fill="freeze"/>
  <image id="image1966" width="178" height="254" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/yiZFUK4.jpg" />
  <g id="SvgjsG1413" class="click-panels">
    <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,13 88,13 88,49 12,49"></polygon>
    <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 81,44 166,44 166,74 81,74"></polygon>
    <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,13 166,13 166,75 12,75"></polygon>
    <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 101,80 166,80 166,118 101,118"></polygon>
    <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,80 166,80 166,147 12,147"></polygon>
    <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,152 91,152 91,200 12,200"></polygon>
    <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 73,171 155,171 155,209 73,209"></polygon>
    <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,198 79,198 79,235 12,235"></polygon>
    <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,152 166,152 166,235 12,235"></polygon>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's answers a large chunk of my question. How do I control the transition/animation with click/swipe events rather than making it automatic?

Comment: `onclick = e => iterate();`

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. However, after the last polygon, I'd like for it to transition to another <svg> and also cycle through the polygons in that one, and so on and so forth. I'm not so proficient in Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You used the svg.js tag, so you get an svg.js answer:

```js
// Reference to svg
const canvas = SVG('#svg1413')

// List of all polygons
const polygons = canvas.find('#SvgjsG1413 polygon')

// List of all bboxes
const boxes = polygons.bbox()

const nextImage = function (index) {
  // Animate viewbox over 1s to new box
  canvas.animate(1000).viewbox(boxes[index])

  // Next image in 2s
  setTimeout(() => nextImage(++index), 2000)
}

nextImage(0)
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

html {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@latest/dist/svg.min.js"></script>


<svg id="svg1413"  class="svg-pg" width="154" height="254" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 178 254" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="transition: .6s ease-out;">
    <image id="image1966" width="178" height="254" clip-path="url('#SvgjsClipPath1413')" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/yiZFUK4.jpg" />
    <g id="SvgjsG1413" clip-path="url('#SvgjsClipPath1413')" class="click-panels">
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,13 88,13 88,49 12,49"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 81,44 166,44 166,74 81,74"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,13 166,13 166,75 12,75"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 101,80 166,80 166,118 101,118"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,80 166,80 166,147 12,147"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,152 91,152 91,200 12,200"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 73,171 155,171 155,209 73,209"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,198 79,198 79,235 12,235"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="transparent" points=" 12,152 166,152 166,235 12,235"></polygon>
    </g>  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it solves a large chunk of my question (a good starting point to tweak things). However, if I wanted to use click/swipe events to control the transitions rather than making them automatic, How do I achieve this. I've updated my main post with the <back> and <forward> buttons.

Comment: Thats something which is basic javascript from there on. For example you can increment a counter whenever the next button is clicked and call nextImage with the incremented counter to show the next picture. Ofc you dont need setTimoute in that case. However, this is a problem which you should be able to solve easily!